# Is there a way to get this scope to return results in batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I have this scope. I would like to have it set up to return batches of 25.

```
scope :get_some_stuff, lambda {
                                select(QUERY_SELECT).
                                joins(QUERY_JOINS).
                                group(QUERY_GROUP_BY)
                          }
```

Comment: So what came about from this? Did my answer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches

Straight from the docs; untested, but I don't see why this wouldn't work.

```
YourUnidentifiedModel.get_some_stuff.find_in_batches(batch_size: 25) do |batch|
  # Work with your batch
end
```